# Neo4j queries slows down but after restart are fast again

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

We started to use Neo4J in production a month ago with Java driver. All queries were fast. Then the response time started to grow. It grew up to ten times. We thought problem is in queries. But we couldn't find anything. Then we just restarted the Neo4J database and queries became fast again. What can be the problem?

It looks like this. Restart can be seen at last Wednesday.

[image: Query response time graph]

Comment: Are emptying the database when you restart?  If so this could simply be that you need to tune the database; e.g. https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/basic-query-tuning-example/

Comment: provider neo4j logs for period when query got slow

Comment: Also look at your GC logs. Maybe too much time is taken by GC due to its mis-configuration with respect to the nature of your queries.

Comment: not enough RAM?